# what is the bluetooth device compatibility matrix?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, compatibility

I have been looking for information that explains what types of bluetooth devices are able to work with each other if they are different versions.

I have a pair of Bluetooth Version 2.1+EDR headphones with A2dp and AVRCP.
They work with a transmitter on my ipod that has the same specification.

I have purchased a transmitter and a receiver that are both bluetooth version 1.2.

Should these version 1.2 devices work with any of my version 2.1 devices?

How does compatibility work among bluetooth device versions in generel?

thanks!
steve

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Specifications_and_features):

> All versions of the Bluetooth standards are designed for downward compatibility.

It means that newest standard supported by both devices will be used.

Comment: Thanks!  So do you know, does that mean that all bluetooth devices should connect with each other regardless of version??

Comment: That's exactly what downward compatibility means.

Comment: Funny,  because I've bought 2 bluetooth devices recently and neither will connect to each other or to any other device I have!  Getting refunds!